# ¿Cómo hacer notificaciones en Laravel 8 con la condición de la hora y minuto en tiempo real?

Tags: laravel, push-notification

estoy usando el sistema de notificaciones de laravel8: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/notifications#introduction, el cual ya lo tengo implementado pero la funcionalidad que le quiero dar es que al crear tareas yo registro en mi Base de Datos la hora en que debo realizarla, por lo que no se me ocurre como poder hacer que a los ejecutivos les aparesca el mensaje de notificación como popup 5 minutos antes de realizarla o en el instante.

Por ejemplo:
Pepe trabajo el Lunes y puso una tarea que debe ejecutar el día Martes a las 17:00 horas. Llega las 16:50 y ojala poder mostrarse la información y notificación de que tienes que realizar cierta actividad.

Entonces mi pregunta sería ¿Cómo podría validar o hacer ese trabajo sin tener que recurrir a que cada minuto me haga llamados a la BD un cronjob o es lo único que puede hacer eso??

El porque digo que ojala no sea cronjobs ya que es un sistema SaaS entonces al tener 5 inquilinos igual puede hacer pesado o lento el sistema.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Notification; 
use Carbon\Carbon;

$date1 =Carbon::now()->subMinutes(5);
$date2 =Carbon::now()->addMinutes(5);

$users = User::all();
Activity::where('due_date, '>=', $date1)->where('due_date, '<=', $date2)->get()->each(function($activity) use ($users) {
    Notification::send($users, new ActivityNotifications($activity));
});
```

Comment: cual es el error que te esta saliendo